# How can I see the task manager and know cpu usage?

Tags: multitasking-view

I am  started using Freya  mostly  now I want to know how can I open the task manager like we have in Windows.  And see the running processe and applications.  Also I want to know the cpu  usage and it's ram usages everything.

Is there any built in feature for it.?

Do I need to install anything for it.?

Answer (score 0):

For a CLI solution, install htop with:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Open the terminal with Win+T, and run it with:

```
htop
```

You will be presented with the information you need. Sorry if it is a command line tool, but it is soo well put together that it is worth trying.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions instead flag them as dup :)